# tornado asynchronous queue not waiting

Tags: python, queue, tornado

I modified the example queue with producer & consumer from this Tornado [documentation](http://tornadokevinlee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/tornado/queues.html#Queue.get), but it doesn't seem like the timeout parameter passed to get() is working at all, as the consumer doesn't wait 10 seconds before throwing the exception.  Ideally, the producer and consumer would run at the same time.  Also, I don't know whether to pass in the timeout parameter as seconds or milliseconds:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.queues import Queue

q = Queue()

@gen.coroutine
def consumer():
    try:
        while True:
            item = yield q.get(timeout=10000)
            try:
                print('Doing work on %s' % item)      
            finally:
                q.task_done()
    except gen.TimeoutError:
        print('timeout')
        return

@gen.coroutine
def producer():
    for item in range(5):
        yield q.put(item)
        print('Put %s' % item)
        yield gen.sleep(2)

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    # Start consumer without waiting (since it never finishes).
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(consumer)
    yield producer()     # Wait for producer to put all tasks.
    yield q.join()       # Wait for consumer to finish all tasks.
    print('Done')

IOLoop.current().run_sync(main)
```

and here is its execution:

```
Put 0
Doing work on 0
timeout
Put 1
Put 2
Put 3
Put 4
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The timeout**

As you can read in [Tornado' Queue.get docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/queues.html#tornado.queues.Queue.get):

> Returns a Future which resolves once an item is available or raises tornado.gen.TimeoutError after a timeout.

But it could be quite misleading, since `timeout` is actually a `deadline`. So it must be specified either with [datetime.timedelta object](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
import datetime
yield q.get(timeout=datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))
```

or absolute time:

```
timeout = 1.5  # in seconds, floats acceptable
deadline = IOLoop.current().time() + timeout
# in most cases IOLoop time is just time.time()
# I've used separate variables only for the notion

yield q.get(timeout=deadline)
```

In [Toro](http://toro.readthedocs.org/en/stable/classes.html#toro.Queue.get), that was merged into Tornado, this argument was called `deadline`.

In your code you specified timeout `10000`, that means deadline to `Thu, 01 Jan 1970 02:46:40 GMT`.

**Consumer loop**

Since you have `try`/`except` block on the whole function, including `while` loop, when `TimeoutError` occurs your consumer stop working. Move exception handling into `while` loop.

Working example:

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.queues import Queue

q = Queue()

@gen.coroutine
def consumer():
    i = 0
    while True:
        i += 1
        print('get cycle %s' % i)
        try:
            item = yield q.get(IOLoop.instance().time() + 3)
            try:
                print('Doing work on %s' % item)
            finally:
                q.task_done()
        except gen.TimeoutError:
            print('timeout')

@gen.coroutine
def producer():
    for item in range(5):
        yield q.put(item)
        print('Put %s' % item)
        yield gen.sleep(2)

@gen.coroutine
def main():
    # Start consumer without waiting (since it never finishes).
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(consumer)
    yield producer()     # Wait for producer to put all tasks.
    yield q.join()       # Wait for consumer to finish all tasks.
    print('Done')
```